# how to compute the intersecting area for n number of spheres, given their radii and center point?

Tags: geometry, 3d

The title says it all...I have already looked at [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html) and found it was only helpful if the spheres were on the same plane, which seems rather useless.